# Firestore useCollectionData call each render

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I wrote a hook to get data from the database, and I use it in a component that is rendered on each row of the table (about 20 times)

As a result, I get 20 requests on each page (if I scroll quickly, I get a request limit)

How to write it correctly so that the request is made once at the first call?

Is it possible to organize a cache or something like that?

My component

```
export const PsaInfoCell: FC<{
  psaInfo?: PsaInfo[]
  eventId?: string
}> = ({ psaInfo, eventId }) => {
  const [psaConnections, isLoading] = usePsaConnections()

  const { loading: isCreationLoading } = useProcessPsaTicket()

  const psaTypes = useMemo<PSA_TYPE[] | undefined>(() => {
    return queuedPsaTypes(psaInfo, psaConnections)
  }, [isLoading, psaConnections])

  if (!psaInfo || (psaTypes && !psaTypes?.length) || !eventId) {
    return <></>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap mt-1 text-xs text-gray-500 max-w-xs">
          <div className="text-gray-900">
            Queued tickets:&nbsp; {isLoading && <CurrentLoader />}
          </div>
          {!isLoading &&
            psaTypes &&
            psaTypes.map((psaType, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="flex break-all whitespace-pre">
                {psaType}
                {isCreationLoading(psaType, eventId) && (
                  <LoaderWithTooltip
                    size={4}
                    tooltipContent={<ul>Ticket creation in progress</ul>}
                  />
                )}
                {i !== psaTypes.length - 1 ? ', ' : ''}
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

My custom hook

```
export const usePsaConnections = () => {
  const { userData } = useAuth()
  const partnerRef = userData?.partner

  const query = useMemo(() => {
    const psaConnectionsRef = db.collection('psaConnections')
    return partnerRef
      ? psaConnectionsRef
          .where('partnerId', '==', partnerRef.id)
          .where('type', 'in', [
            PSA_TYPE.CONNECTWISE,
            PSA_TYPE.AUTOTASKPSA,
            PSA_TYPE.KASEYA,
          ])
      : null
  }, [db])
  const [psaConnections, isLoading] = useCollectionData<IPsaConnection>(query, {
    idField: 'id',
  })

  return [psaConnections, isLoading]
}
```

Comment: React hooks don't share any "state". Try centralizing the fetching logic in a React context to it's fetched once, and provide the value via the context provider.